# Strange behavior in Facebook login with PHP SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm learning about Facebook apps programming and I've wroted the next code that works OK, but if I comment the indicated line in the "do-login.php" file, then when I call getUser() on "index.php" will return 0.

I'm curious about that and I think maybe I'am doing something bad.

At this point, I think it wouldn't be necessary to create a Facebook object in the "do-login.php" file.

Finally, note that the link on "index.php" file points to the Heroku URL, and the link on "do-login.php" file points to the "apps.facebook.com" URL... this is the only way I found to the code works.

Any advice, please ? I'm confussed with this and I spent a day and half to get working this

Thanks!

## index.php

```
    <?php

    require_once("facebook.php");

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => THE_APP_ID,
        'secret' => THE_APP_SECRET,
        'fileUpload' => false,          
        'cookie' => true,
        'trustForwarded' => true,
        'allowSignedRequest' => false  
    ));

    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if( $user ) 
    {
        try 
        {
            $user_info = $facebook->api(THE_USER_ID?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,email&access_token='.$facebook->getAccessToken());

            echo "getUser(): ".$user."<br/>";
            echo "<b>Name</b>: ".$user_info['name'];
        } 
        catch( FacebookApiException $e ) 
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    else
    {     
        $facebook_login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'scope' => 'email, read_stream, user_interests, user_likes, user_location, user_status',
            'redirect_uri' => 'https://MY-APP.herokuapp.com/do-login.php' 
        ));

        echo "<p><a href='".$facebook_login_url."' target='_top'>Login</a></p>";
    } 
?>
```

## do-login.php

```
    <?php

    require_once("facebook.php");

    if( isset($_GET['code']) )
    {
        echo "<p><b>¡¡ Se autorizó la app !!</b></p>";

        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => THE_APP_ID,
            'secret' => THE_APP_SECRET,
            'fileUpload' => false,          
            'cookie' => true,
            'trustForwarded' => true,
            'allowSignedRequest' => false       
            )); 

        // PROBLEM IS that if I comment this line, getUser() will return 0 when called in index.php
        echo $facebook->getUser();

        echo "<p><a href='https://apps.facebook.com/MY-APP/index.php' >Go back</a></p>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error: ".$_GET['error']."<br />";
        echo "Description: ".$_GET['error_description'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: If you don’t call `getUser`, then nothing will be _done_ with the `code` parameter that the script received – and then, when you are back in your index.php, that parameter is not present any more, and therefor the SDK can’t determine the user id. What is your do-login.php script good for anyway? The SDK is perfectly capable of detecting the presence of the `code` parameter by itself – so you don’t even need that script – just initialize the SDK in your index.php, and set that URL as the redirect_uri to come back to _after_ the login dialog.

Comment: Understood, seeing the example of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi/ I thought the SDK internally control the logon to see that did not account for the variable 'code'.

My initial intention was to instantiate the Facebook object in "do-login.php", serialize it to avoid having to re-instantiated on each page, and calling getUser() when necessary.

Although not if it is good practice in this case, I'm still learning.

Thanks !